# Ruby: NameError: uninitialized constant TestKit::Case32::SomeSuite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having following problem.

```
module TestKit
  class Case32 < Case
## Initialization

def initialize
  super("test")
end

## Methods

def run(context)
  # Required services
  someService = context.resources.someFile


  id = SomeSuite.create_random_file(context)
.....rest of the code.....
```

And SomeSuite file contains below code

```
module TestKit


class SomeSuite < Suite

## Initialization

def initialize()
  super("file", {
    "Test1" => [Case31.new, Case32.new, Case33.new, Case34.new, Case41.new],
    "Test2" => [Case35.new, Case36.new, Case37.new, Case38.new],
  })
end

## Methods


def self.create_random_file(context)

  # Required services
  someService = context.resources.file
```

When i run tests it gives me uninitialised error. Cant find anything specific while searching and i am new to ruby so that makes a kittle but harder.

Any Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they are in different files, you should require *SomeSuite* file in *Case32* file.

```
require './<SomeSuite_file_name>'
# require_relative '<SomeSuite_file_name>'
module TestKit
  class Case32 < Case
## Initialization

def initialize
  super("test")
end
```